# Custom encryption algorithm, "SBC"

Tags: c#, caesar-cipher

I decided to roll out my own encryption algorithm, which I am calling "SBC" or Simple Byte Cipher. Essentially, I just take the bytes of the string data, do a Caesar cipher like shift to it, increment through an array of password bytes for each byte in the data (this enables the same letters such as `"T"` to not always have the same output, which would be easily crackable). And in the end I just reverse the process to glean the original data.

My code seems to work just fine; decryption works like a dream. I just want to know if there is a better way, or any hidden errors that may occur with the code as it currently stands.

I am aware that the length of the password and data are not length tested, or null tested. I will address that later.

```
public static class SimpleByteCipher
    {
        public static byte[] EncryptStringToByteArray( string data , string password )
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( data );
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( password );
            int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
            for( int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++ )
            {
                bytes[ i ] = ( byte )( bytes[ i ] + passwordBytes[ passwordShiftIndex ] );
                passwordShiftIndex = ( passwordShiftIndex + 1 ) % passwordBytes.Length;
            }
            return bytes;
        }

        public static string DecryptByteArrayToString( byte[] data , string password )
        {
            byte[] bytes = data;
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( password );
            int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
            for( int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++ )
            {
                bytes[ i ] = ( byte )( bytes[ i ] - passwordBytes[ passwordShiftIndex ] );
                passwordShiftIndex = ( passwordShiftIndex + 1 ) % passwordBytes.Length;
            }
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString( bytes );
        }

        public static byte[] EncryptStringToByteArray( string data , string password , uint seed)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( data );
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( password );
            int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
            for( int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++ )
            {
                bytes[ i ] = ( byte )( bytes[ i ] + passwordBytes[ passwordShiftIndex ] + seed );
                passwordShiftIndex = ( passwordShiftIndex + 1 ) % passwordBytes.Length;
            }
            return bytes;
        }

        public static string DecryptByteArrayToString( byte[] data , string password , uint seed)
        {
            byte[] bytes = data;
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( password );
            int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
            for( int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++ )
            {
                bytes[ i ] = ( byte )( bytes[ i ] - passwordBytes[ passwordShiftIndex ] - seed );
                passwordShiftIndex = ( passwordShiftIndex + 1 ) % passwordBytes.Length;
            }
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString( bytes );
        }
    }
```

And here is a practice main:

> ```
> class Program
>     {
>         static void Main( string[] args )
>         {
>             string data = "This is but a test.";
>             byte[] encrypted = SimpleByteCipher.EncryptStringToByteArray( data , "Test" , 5000 );
>             string decrypted = SimpleByteCipher.DecryptByteArrayToString( encrypted , "Test" , 5000 );
>             Console.WriteLine( decrypted );
>             Console.ReadLine();
>         }
>      }
> ```

The output correctly prints:

> "This is but a test."

And here is a visualization of what the encrypted bytes look like in a text file:[image]

Comment: I don't get to say this often, but you have a *great* use of horizontal whitespace. Kudos. Could use a bit more vertical space though. Use it to group together small bits of code that logically group together, but shouldn't be broken into their own methods (for whatever reason).

Comment: @RubberDuck I am extremely anal about how my code looks. Call it OCD, but it seriously bothers me when things are not appropriately separated by spaces.

Comment: At the risk of getting chatty, is there a way to configure VS to add the extra space around indexes like you've done here? I really like that.

Comment: @RubberDuck Yes. I have it set up so I just hit Ctrl+K+D and it does it all for me in split second.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to play with the settings tomorrow. =)

Comment: It should also be noted for anyone who chooses to use this code, that when you print it to a document with WriteAllBytes, it has the gibberish appearance of binary files. =D

Comment: @RubberDuck, just goes to show how personal and subjective code layout is, for my first reaction was "this code contains an unreadable mess of whitespace".  It completely ignores C# coding conventions and makes the code harder to read then it need be.

Comment: Problems with this code: 1. "I decided to roll out my own encryption algorithm". Unless you are a mathematician specialising in cryptography, that was a bad decision.  2. The code is highly repetitive and ignores DRY principles. Only ASCII strings are supported, rather than UTF8. 3. The code layout ignores C# conventions around white space.

Comment: @DavidArno The only person who complains about coding conventions is someone who has never actually worked professionally in software engineering. Coding styles change based on the company or group you work for. I am ignoring the rest of your comment because it is based upon arbitrary opinion that in no way validates the question that has been posed.

Comment: One thing that seems rather unneeded is the use of a seed.  There doesn't seem to be a secure way to pass the seed to the end user.  If it's intended to be part of the password, then it would make more sense to grab it from the password.  If obfuscating is more the object than actual encryption, passing the text through something like Base85 encoding, then encrypting, would probably work better.  This would also allow it to display as mixed text.

Comment: 1) This algorithm is know as [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher). 2) This is just for fun and you didn't try to write secure encryption, right?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I would say that it is a permutation of the basic concept, but in truth, it is a cipher all its own. I iterate and transform bytes(integers), which just happen to be mappable to various keys.

Answer (score 6):

## Reduce Duplication

There appears to be some significant code duplication between the encrypt and decrypt methods.

### Method Overloads

The first and most obvious spots we can refactor are the overloads for your decrypt and encrypt functions:

```
public static byte[] EncryptStringToByteArray( string data , string password )
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( data );
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( password );
    int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++ )
    {
        bytes[ i ] = ( byte )( bytes[ i ] + passwordBytes[ passwordShiftIndex ] );
        passwordShiftIndex = ( passwordShiftIndex + 1 ) % passwordBytes.Length;
    }
    return bytes;
}

public static byte[] EncryptStringToByteArray( string data , string password , uint seed)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( data );
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( password );
    int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++ )
    {
        bytes[ i ] = ( byte )( bytes[ i ] + passwordBytes[ passwordShiftIndex ] + seed );
        passwordShiftIndex = ( passwordShiftIndex + 1 ) % passwordBytes.Length;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

The only difference between these two is that one takes in a seed and adds it to the bytes within the loop.  The overload without a seed can be rewritten as follows:

```
public static byte[] EncryptStringToByteArray(string data, string password)
{
    return EncryptStringToByteArray(data, password, 0);
}
```

A similar refactor can be done with the two decrypt overloads.  I will leave that step as an exercise for the reader.

### Symmetric Encryption

With what's left, I cannot help but notice that this appears to be a symmetric encryption algorithm.  As a result, the encrypt and decrypt steps are nearly identical to one another:

```
public static byte[] EncryptStringToByteArray( string data , string password , uint seed)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( data );
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( password );
    int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++ )
    {
        bytes[ i ] = ( byte )( bytes[ i ] + passwordBytes[ passwordShiftIndex ] + seed );
        passwordShiftIndex = ( passwordShiftIndex + 1 ) % passwordBytes.Length;
    }
    return bytes;
}

public static string DecryptByteArrayToString( byte[] data , string password , uint seed)
{
    byte[] bytes = data;
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( password );
    int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++ )
    {
        bytes[ i ] = ( byte )( bytes[ i ] - passwordBytes[ passwordShiftIndex ] - seed );
        passwordShiftIndex = ( passwordShiftIndex + 1 ) % passwordBytes.Length;
    }
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString( bytes );
}
```

They do, however, have some subtle differences:

- Encrypt adds the seed, while Decrypt subtracts it
- Encrypt takes in `string` and returns `byte[]`, while Decrypt takes in `byte[]` and returns `string`.

However, neither are particularly large differences.  We can refactor further if we extract the following method:

```
private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytes, string password, uint seed, int factor)
{
    var passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
    var passwordShiftIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = (byte) (bytes[i] + factor * (passwordBytes[passwordShiftIndex] + seed));
        passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % passwordBytes.Length;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Note the following changes:

- It takes in and returns `byte[]`
- I added an integer factor variable which is used to control whether `passwordBytes[passwordShiftIndex]` and `seed` are added or subtracted

With those changes, we can refactor our seeded encrypt and decrypt methods to call the above method, changing the class as follows:

```
public static class SimpleByteCipher
{
    public static byte[] EncryptStringToByteArray(string data, string password)
    {
        return EncryptStringToByteArray(data, password, 0);
    }

    public static byte[] EncryptStringToByteArray(string data, string password, uint seed)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        return Encrypt(bytes, password, seed, 1);
    }

    private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytes, string password, uint seed, int factor)
    {
        var passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
        var passwordShiftIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte) (bytes[i] + factor * (passwordBytes[passwordShiftIndex] + seed));
            passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % passwordBytes.Length;
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string DecryptByteArrayToString(byte[] data, string password)
    {
        return DecryptByteArrayToString(data, password, 0);
    }

    public static string DecryptByteArrayToString(byte[] data, string password, uint seed)
    {
        var bytes = Encrypt(data, password, seed, -1);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestions, except for the overzealous use of the var keyword.

Comment: In your (de|en)crypt simplifiction you missed that passwordBytes[ passwordShiftIndex ] in also flipped from added to subtracted.

Comment: @ShaunH I think your comment got cut off, but I think I see what you're getting at - I missed the sign change for passwordBytes.  Good catch.

Comment: @DanLyons Yeah grabbed what i wanted and started to write around it. Then my brain forgot that enter submits in comments.